# removeRange method with ArrayList

Tags: java

Having trouble figuring this method out for class. I have to write a method that takes the range of a max and min and removes all elements containing those values. FOr example, if I put in the main method removeRange(list, 5, 7); in the main method, it should take the values of [7, 9, 4, 2, 7, 7, 5, 3, 5, 1, 7, 8, 6, 7] and turn it to [9, 4, 2, 3, 1, 8] . But I keep getting [9, 4, 2, 7, 3, 1, 8, 7] when I compile. Here is my removeRange method with the parameters.

```
public static void removeRange(ArrayList<Integer> list, int min, int max) {     

        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if((list.get(i) >= min && list.get(i) <= max)) {
                list.remove(i);
            }
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

When you remove an element from your `ArrayList`, the indices of the elements following the removed element are decremented, so your loop would skip the next element in the following iteration.

You can account for it by decrementing `i` when you remove an element:

```
public static void removeRange(ArrayList<Integer> list, int min, int max) {     
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if((list.get(i) >= min && list.get(i) <= max)) {
            list.remove(i);
            i--;
        }
    }   
}
```

Or by iterating backwards:

```
public static void removeRange(ArrayList<Integer> list, int min, int max) {     
    for(int i = list.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if((list.get(i) >= min && list.get(i) <= max)) {
            list.remove(i);
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your array `7, 9, 4, 2, 7, 7, 5, 3, 5, 1, 7, 8, 6, 7` the iteration goes like this ->
Let range be 7 to 7 for ease.

initially, i = 0, size = 14: 7 is removed. size = 13
new array - 9, 4, 2, 7, 7, 5, 3, 5, 1, 7, 8, 6, 7

now i = 1, size = 13: you are now accessing a[1] ie, 4 so 9 is skipped.

later i = 3, size =13, 7 is removed. size = 12
new array - 9, 4, 2, 7, 5, 3, 5, 1, 7, 8, 6, 7

now i = 4, size = 12: you are now accessing a[4] ie, 5 so 7 is skipped.

hope the flaw in your logic is visible to you now.
Try doing i = i-1 every time you remove an element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Iterator` like this.

```
public static void removeRange(ArrayList<Integer> list, int min, int max) {     
    for (Iterator<Integer> i = list.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
        int element = i.next();
        if (element >= min && element <= max)
            i.remove();
    }
}
```

and

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(List.of(7, 9, 4, 2, 7, 7, 5, 3, 5, 1, 7, 8, 6, 7));
removeRange(list, 5, 7);
System.out.println(list);
```

output:

```
[9, 4, 2, 3, 1, 8]
```